# Hidden field attributes not being added to mysqli table from PHP file

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am required to send data from hidden field attributes in a HTML file to a mysqli mariadb SQL table. For some reason the data is not being sent to the table. Here is the code of the PHP file that should send the data to the table:

```
require_once ("settings.php");
    $conn = @mysqli_connect($host,
    $user,
    $pwd,
    $sql_db
);

if (!$conn){
    echo $errMsg = $errMsg. "<p>Database connection failure</p>";
} 
    $sql_table="orders";
    $fname = trim($_POST["fname"]);
    $lname = trim($_POST["lname"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $address = trim($_POST["address"]);
    $suburb = trim($_POST["suburb"]);
    $state = trim($_POST["state"]);
    $postcode = trim($_POST["postcode"]);
    $mobile = trim($_POST["mobile"]);
    $prefContact = trim($_POST["contact"]);
    $plan = trim($_POST["plan"]);
    $option = trim($_POST["option"]);
    $months = trim($_POST["months"]);
    $install = trim($_POST["install"]);
    $creditName = trim($_POST["creditName"]);
    $creditNumber = trim($_POST["creditNumber"]);
    $creditExpiry = trim($_POST["creditExpiry"]);
    $CVV = trim($_POST["CVV"]);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `orders`(`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES ('testName2', $lname)";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if(!'result'){
        echo "<p class=\"wrong\">Something is wrong with ", $query, "</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p class=\"ok\">Succesfully added a new order to records</p>";
        //header('Location: receipt.php');
    }
mysqli_close($conn);
```

The values that I am entering are 1) a test string to see if it is merely me not obtaining the variables correctly and 2) an attempt for me to insert another variable.

Comment: are you facing any error?

Comment: it might be handy to see the html form too - though there looks to be plenty of scope in the above code for errors so have you checked the PHP error log??

Comment: Is it correct you a using ` instead of '?

Comment: assuming that `$lname` is a string then you are missing quotes from around the variable in the sql `'testName2', $lname` should be `'testName2', '$lname'` but this remains vulnerable and should be changed to use prepared statements. Also `if(!'result')` is wrong - that ought to be `if(!$result)`

Answer (score 0):

Use like this...

`$query = "INSERT INTO`orders`SET`first_name`='".$testName2."',`last_name`='".$lname."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);`

Answer (score 0):

The original code had a few errors ( highlighted in comments )and was not really a good way in which to proceed when manipulating database contents using `user supplied input` - [See here for more about SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/about)

Whilst I cannot say that what follows is the definitive method that should be used ( far from it ) it should give you a good idea how you could proceed and generally make your code more reliable and safer.

```
<?php
    try{
        /* 
            An array of expected fields in the POST array
            with the appropriate filter type ~ see the 
            manual for more detail

            http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php
            http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php
            http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php

        */
        $args=array(
            'fname'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'lname'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'email'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
            'address'       =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'suburb'        =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'state'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'postcode'      =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'mobile'        =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'contact'       =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'plan'          =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'option'        =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'months'        =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'install'       =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'creditName'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'creditNumber'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'creditExpiry'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'CVV'           =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );

        /* 
            Permit only those form fields that appear in the 
            above array - unknown fields will cause an 
            exception
        */
        foreach( $_POST as $param => $value ){
            if( !in_array( $param, array_keys( $args ) ) ) throw new Exception( sprintf( 'Invalid/unknown parameter: %s ', $param ) );
        }
        /*
            Filter the form data according to rules above
        */
        filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
        /*
            remove empty fields from the POST array
        */
        $_POST = array_filter( $_POST );

        /*
            Extract the params/values to variables
            ie: will produce variables of same name as field
        */
        extract( $_POST );





        require_once( "settings.php" );
        $conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pwd,$sql_db);


        /* 
            if these two fields were populated in the POST data 
            they should be available here as variables of the 
            same name
        */
        if( $fname && $lname ){

            $sql = "insert into `orders` ( `first_name`, `last_name` ) values (?,?);";
            $stmt= $conn->prepare( $sql );

            if( !$stmt ) throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql query');

            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $fname, $lname );
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();

            $message = $result ? '<p class="ok">Succesfully added a new order to records</p>' : sprintf('<p class="wrong">Something is wrong with %s</p>', $sql );
            /*
                redirect? display $message?
            */
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Bad Foo!');
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( $e->getMessage() );
    }   
?>
```

The links from the PHP website

- [Sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)
- [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)
- [filter_input_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php)